# What is the purpose of the IBMBluemix.getLogger() API?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Looking at some of the sample code for hybrid mobile apps that speak to Node.js on BM (http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/hybrid), you will see various examples that demonstrate how to use a logger on the *client* side:

```
var config = {
    applicationId:'<applicationId>',
    applicationRoute:'<applicationRoute>',
    applicationSecret:'<applicationSecret>'
};

IBMBluemix.initialize(config).done(function(status){
    // Initialize the Services
}).catch(function(err){
    IBMBluemix.getLogger().error("Error intializing SDK");
});
```

I've confirmed this works fine in a Cordova app. My question is - why does this exist? As far as I can see, it does nothing more than wrap calls to console.log. It does not ever send logs to the Bluemix server app as far as I can tell.

There is documentation here, https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobile/mobilecloud/nodejsmobile.html#log, that talks about the feature both server-side and client-side, but unless I'm missing it, there's no persistence for the client-side version.

If so - then what exactly is the point of this abstraction then? I have to imagine it was built for some reason, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

this wrapper is used to "wrap" and to make "standard" the console log api, especially because this javascript API isn't available for all the browsers (especially old ones). By wrapping it the library could check the browser and its availability, in order to avoid an execution error
Another reasons is to wrap some configuration utilities, like providing different libraries to use (eg log4js) or other configuration, and so on.
Last but not least, probably it provide a singleton interface for performance optimization

Comment: Hmm. I suppose that makes sense, but honestly, the # of browsers w/o console is minimal, and you should not be using console outside of development anyway. The docs should really be more clear about what the client side logger does, as it stands right now I would not recommend using it.

Comment: Neither jQuery gives you any details of what its wrapper methods do inside, unless you read its source code.
It is a wrapper, it gives some utilities to use or not, but everyone is free to use his own utilities